# How to calculate area with two variable using a function?

Tags: java, function

i m solving this question in order to calculate area with answer of double and int.it didnt work, whats wrong with code?

i try to include double radius and int radius inside, it showed cannot be applied to given types.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
     for (int radius = 0; radius < 5 ; radius++)
         PrintArea(radius);
    for (double  radius = 0; radius < 2.6 ; radius+= 0.5)
         PrintArea(radius);
}
public static void PrintArea(int radius,double radius){
        double area=3.142*radius*radius;
        System.out.println(area);

}
```

i expect it could be calculated and shows answer in double ,but it shows error.

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: Your `PrintArea` have two arguments, but when you call you are sending only one parameter. Is this a javascript code?

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript?  It looks like Java, which is a different language.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, you **should not use** the same name for two parameters of a function.

So `PrintArea(int radius, double radius)` is incorrect and is probably one of the errors you're getting.

The other one, is that you are calling PrintArea with only one parameter, when it expects two.

Rename your parameters int r1 and double r2 instead, like so:

```
public static void PrintArea(int r1,double r2){
    double area=3.142*radius*radius;
    System.out.println(area);
}
```

Or use a PrintArea with only one parameter, of type double:

```
public static void PrintArea(double radius){
    double area=3.142*radius*radius;
    System.out.println(area);
}
```

Comment: an int can be passed as a double parameter without any problems, the converse is not true: i.e. passing a double when you expect an int might truncate your double (1.1 would be passed as 1).

Answer (score 0):

There are certain issues with your code, your printArea function accepts two arguments, but you are sending only
one while calling the function. Your printArea function needs only one parameter `radius` (no need of two parameters). The other issue is 
that within your printArea function, the `data type` of  parameter is of type `int`. So when you call this
function with different parameter other than `int`, it will throw error, as you are calling the function `printArea` with parameters of type `double` in your second `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on that can be cleaned up. First of all, why does the `PrintArea` function need 2 parameters? You call it with only one, and just thinking generally, we don't need two pieces of information to get the area of a circle. So I'm going to guess that you meant only one parameter.

```
public static void PrintArea(double radius){
  double area=3.142*radius*radius;
  System.out.println(area);
}
```

Which will work for both `int` and `double` types. Usually we also use camelCase in Java, which means that for methods like "PrintArea" which is made up of multiple words, the first word starts with a lowercase letter, and every other word after that starts with an uppercase letter.